# Set ytPlayer start and end time

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I'am using `YouTube JavaScript Player API`.
 I want to play a youtube video from and end it at a specific time. In other words The `youtube` videos is too long and I want to play A small section of the video programmatically.

I tried to use these two methods

```
    [self.inlinePlayer loadVideoById:videoId startSeconds:5.0 endSeconds:10.0 suggestedQuality:kYTPlaybackQualityAuto];

    [self.inlinePlayer cueVideoById startSeconds:5.0 endSeconds:10.0 suggestedQuality:kYTPlaybackQualityAuto];
```

This let the video start from the `startSeconds` but does not do any effect for the `endSeconds`.
Is there is any way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

look at https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Functions

```
loadVideoById({
    'videoId': 'bHQqvYy5KYo',
    'startSeconds': 5,
    'endSeconds': 60,
    'suggestedQuality': 'large'
});
```

Comment: I mentioned above in the question, I have tried this method and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube JavaScript Player API was [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube-api-list) back in January of this year, so it's likely that it won't work the way you expect it to. You should be using the [IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) instead.